# NodeJS error initializing V8 on Gentoo AMD64

Tags: node.js, v8

I managed to compile V8 engine on the machine, however when I type

> $ node
>
> FATAL ERROR: v8::Debug::SetDebugMessageDispatchHandler Error initializing V8

I have V8 version 3.6.6.11, the D8 console is working properly. 
I've tried portage version of nodejs 0.6.6, compiled version from github shows the same error.
I guess the problem is with heap of stack allocation

> $ ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31707
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31707
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

It is a virtual machine, that might raise some limitations...

> Linux 2.6.36-hardened-r9-guest-hardened-01 x86_64 QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.13.0 AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
>   Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after debuggin nodejs with Vyacheslav Egorov we found out, that `mmap` is failing to allocate memory (`Operation not permitted`) - this is caused by some Gentoo's security flag (changing it might require to recompile kernel)

Finally I used node v0.6 branch from github

```
./configure --without-snapshot
make
make install
```

and

```
paxctl -m /usr/local/bin/node
```

which adds `MPROTECT` flag

```
- PaX flags: -----m-x-e-- [/usr/local/bin/node]
        MPROTECT is disabled
        RANDEXEC is disabled
        EMUTRAMP is disabled
```

**Note to myself:**

when running Rails application on server put to `config/boot.rb`

```
ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node' if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
```

Comment: In my instance, I only needed the paxctl command after emerging nodejs, no need for custom build.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is caused by failure to allocate code range (it is used only in x64 version of V8). In `deps/v8/src/heap.cc` try changing `code_range_size_(512*MB),` to `code_rage_size_(32*MB),` and recompile node.

Comment: I used shared v8 library because when I try to compile V8 on my own I get this error: `-lpthread
obj/release/mksnapshot obj/release/snapshot.cc #
# Fatal error in v8::Context::New()
# Error initializing V8
#
`

Comment: V8 has to initialize itself as a part of building process to make so called *snapshot*. `mksnapshot` most probably fails to start for the very same reason your node later fails to start. Please try the change I proposed, this is the most common source of initialization failures on resource constrained x64 systems. If I am right then it should solve both build problem and node start up problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get from `/var/log/kern.log` when compiling V8 for Android:

> `Dec 30 11:42:26 stormrage kernel: grsec: From 82.247.154.152: denied RWX mmap of <anonymous mapping> by /mnt/sdb/cyanogen/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/bin/mksnapshot[mksnapshot:32426] uid/euid:1014/1014 gid/egid:1014/1014, parent /usr/bin/gmake[make:28416] uid/euid:1014/1014 gid/egid:1014/1014`

I suspect your error is the same as mine (GRSEC issue) and doing

> `paxctl -m /mnt/sdb/cyanogen/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/bin/mksnapshot`

works for me. 
I'm under Gentoo x64 Hardened as a VMWare ESXi guest.
 Thanks.