# nodejs give error Error initializing V8 on cent os

Tags: python, node.js, openstack, openstack-horizon

I am trying to run openstack horizon to my system. When I try to connect to horizon it give error

```
FATAL ERROR: v8::Debug::SetDebugMessageDispatchHandler Error initializing V8
```

When I check in code it giving due to `nodejs` problem.

I also search on net and found some solution like memory leak or others but that didn't work for me. I gave unlimited memory to virtual memory.

```
[test@localhost ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 62849
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I check [NodeJS error initializing V8 on Gentoo AMD64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655682/nodejs-error-initializing-v8-on-gentoo-amd64) but that also not help. :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, because you are using this on a redhat build, there is no node.js packages.

I know that there was a plan to make it possible to disable the need for node.js in redhat.

but I am not sure whether that ever materialized.

An option for continuing would be to install node.js from a third party repository.  Or build your own package.

Example for third party:

```
yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://nodejs.tchol.org/repocfg/fedora/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm
yum -y install nodejs nodejs-compat-symlinks
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Comment: Thanks MattJoyce. I tried to get stable rpm from your given third party repo. But that server is down :(. Will you please give me another third party repo from where I can download stable nodejs ?

Comment: I also try to download stable release from http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/03/02/version-0-6-12-stable/ but that also give error 

scons: Building targets ...
obj/release/mksnapshot obj/release/snapshot.cc --logfile "/test/out/Release/obj/release/snapshot.log" --log-snapshot-positions

#
# Fatal error in v8::Context::New()
# Error initializing V8
#
scons: *** [obj/release/snapshot.cc] Error -6
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Waf: Leaving directory `/root/node-v0.6.12/out'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2):
        {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}
make: *** [program] Error 1